# 私 (watashi) vs 僕 (boku)

Tags: word-choice, usage, first-person-pronouns, register

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Is it ok for non-japanese to refer to themselves as 僕（ぼく） and if not why?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/580/is-it-ok-for-non-japanese-to-refer-to-themselves-as-and-if-not-why)
>   [How should I select what first-person pronoun to use?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/74/how-should-i-select-what-first-person-pronoun-to-use)
>   [How commonly are "あたし" (atashi) or "僕" (boku) used in Japan?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/952/how-commonly-are-atashi-or-boku-used-in-japan)

**one teacher said:**

> When we are talking about kids, we differenciate boys and girls
>
> - 私：for girls
> - 僕：for boys
>
> for adults, it doesn't matter

**another teacher:**

> it's expected that I refer to myself as 僕 always, because I'm a man

**one japanese friend:**

> 僕 seems little cute

**my brother:**

> always use 俺 within friends

...
I always try to use 私
how is the best way to say "I" or "me" (for boys, and for girls)?

Comment: For some reason, I can't click the "close" button after entering an URL.
This question has been asked and answered there: 
http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/74/how-should-i-select-what-first-person-pronoun-to-use
http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/952/how-commonly-are-atashi-or-boku-used-in-japan
http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/580/is-it-ok-for-non-japanese-to-refer-to-themselves-as-and-if-not-why

Comment: yeah. sorry. i searched it, but i couldn't find it. maybe i should have looked for more. my mistake

Comment: No problem, the title is different so maybe it'll help point future searchers in the right direction.

Comment: @danieltomio Just curious.. your brother is a native speaker?