# What is the implication when a girl refers to herself using "うち"? Is it meant to be more or less feminine? Neutral? Tomboyish?

Tags: meaning, culture, dialects

I realize it is a kind of Kansai-ben but how does it compare to　the other forms of "I" in terms of how they want to represent themselves?

Comment: I feel like this question is a duplicate, but if it is, I can't find it.  Anyway, related:  [How should I select what first-person pronoun to use?](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/74/78)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think うち is a neutral and common feminine first-person pronoun, at least in part of Kansai region. There, people who use うち use it because everyone else uses it. As long as it is used with fluent Kansai-ben in an informal setting, I would feel nothing special about うち.

Wikipedia says うち is used also by male people in certain regions in Kyushu, but I have not heard that.

Another point is that うち is a casual pronoun, just like 俺. Although some Kansai comedians and *geisha* are always using it on TV, I usually don't hear うち from Kansai people in a serious situation.