# Can personal pronouns be written in hiragana?

Tags: hiragana

Would it be frowned upon to say for example ぼく instead of 僕？Or わたし instead of 私？Is it just a stylistic choice or do these have to be in kanji?

Answer (score 3):

This depends on the pronoun.

- Some casual first-person pronouns are almost always written in hiragana because there are no ways to write them in kanji in the first place: うち, わい, あたし
- Some stilted first-person pronouns are always written in kanji: 小生, 朕
- Many common first-person pronouns can be written both in kanji and in hiragana. Basically it's a matter of taste, but generally speaking, the more casual the situation is, the more frequently hiragana is used.

  - Many adults choose to keep using わたし instead of 私. See: [Why is 私 a sixth grade kanji?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/62132/5010)
  - 僕 is not even a 教育漢字, but the majority of adults use kanji.
  - 俺 is usually spelled with kanji, but おれ and オレ are not uncommon.
  - 儂 is usually わし, but 儂 is not uncommon in novels.

Comment: thanks! when would someone use わい and うち？and in that case could 僕 be written with hiragana or would that be odd?

Comment: @jacoballens What do you mean by "in that case"? Users of [うち](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/18481/5010) do not use 僕.

Comment: i meant in the case that 僕 is not 教育漢字

Comment: @jacoballens わい is  used by people from Kansai region, though at times just for comical effect.